# GCP VM - only using 30% resources running Keras Script

Tags: python, linux, keras, google-cloud-platform

I am running a Keras script on a detached screen on a GCP VM (n1-standard-16 (16 vCPUs, 60 GB memory) and the CPU usage accoriding to GCP hovers around 30%.  I heard that python 32-bit can only use a maximum of 4GB memory, but I checked and I am using Python 3.5 64-bit.  I have run top and the output is below.

Could anyone explain why the script is not able to make more use of the VM resource capacity?  Also, could someone explain why the CPU is showing as more than 100%?

```
top - 10:40:45 up  3:47,  1 user,  load average: 4.83, 4.47, 4.47
Tasks: 184 total,   1 running, 183 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 17.2 us,  8.6 sy,  0.0 ni, 74.2 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem : 61851636 total,  4809744 free, 55865760 used,  1176132 buff/cache
KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 free,        0 used.  5384248 avail Mem 

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                                                                                           
 3076 delaicog  20   0 56.465g 0.052t 107064 S 453.5 89.8 350:51.07 python3                                                                                                                                                                           
 3511 delaicog  20   0   42956   3708   2944 R   0.3  0.0   0:00.19 top
```

Answer (score 0):

To understand why your CPU is showing as +100%  you have to take a look at your load average, which is:

```
 load average: 4.83, 4.47, 4.47
```

The three values represent the load average for the last 1 minute, 5 minutes and 15 minutes respectively.

A load average of 1.00 would represent that you are using exactly the capacity of your CPU, not a bit less, and not a bit more is needed. This means that your CPU capacity matches exactly what you need.

When you start to go over 1.00 this means that you would need *more* processing power than you actually have. At this point the work starts to pile up and queue and your system performance is impacted.

A load average of around 4 as you are seeing means that, to execute all the processes you would need roughly x4 the processing power you have. This is represented on %CPU by showing your CPU load as 400%.

It doesn't matter if you have 16 vCPU if you script isn't multi-threaded enough, so your bottleneck right now is the performance per core.

This is also the reason you are not using more RAM even if it's available. It's not necessary, all your system is lagging behind waiting for the processor to finish its calculations, and even if there are more resources available (more cores, more RAM) they are not used because they are not needed.